# Create jar file that takes in input file to Main and outputs an output file in some directory

Tags: java, json, scala, jar, jvm

I have a Scala project that I want to export as a jar file so I can run it on another machine(I know how to export as a jar file). My main function reads in an existing `input.json` file and writes to a `output.json` file. The path where the the `input.json` is hard coded in my main and the path where the `output.json` will be written is hard coded as well. My goal is to export a jar file and pass in multiple `input.json` files to this jar file and my desire is the `output.json` file to be written to some directory. Basically, I want to have a large pipeline that feeds many different `input.json` files to this jar file and outputs all the `output.json` to some directory. I'm not too sure if this can be done, and if so how exactly?

Comment: Can you make changes to the scala project so that the name/path of the output and input file can be given as parameters on the command line? If not a simple script that for each of the many input files copies it to the hard coded path and moves the output to some alternate directory is fairly easy to write.

Comment: @EmilH Yes I can make changes to the scala project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the path  from the configuration and from the environment variables and if the environment variable is not present it will pick up the path from the Configuration.
Change the environmental variable according to your needs and there you go.!

But in the case you want a whole directory to be taken as input containing multiple json files. Then in that case you have to implement a hack !

Read the directory path from the configuration file or environmental variable, and read it as directory, extract the list of names and perform operations on them inside a map !

I hope I answered your query!